surjective morphism $\mathscr O_X^{\oplus r}\rightarrow \mathscr F$ has finite type kernel when $\mathscr F$ is finitely presented
The following is Stacks 01BP:

Lemma. Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite presentation.

If $\psi:\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus r}\to\mathcal{F}$ is a surjection, then $\ker\psi$ is of finite type.
If $\theta:\mathcal{G}\to\mathcal{F}$ is surjective with $\mathcal{G}$ of finite type, then $\ker\theta$ is of finite type.

Proof. Proof of (1). Let $x\in X$. Choose an open neighborhood $U\subset X$ of $x$ such that there exists a presentation $$\mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus m} \stackrel{\chi}{\to} \mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus n} \stackrel{\varphi}{\to} \mathcal{F}|_U \to 0.$$ Let $e_k$ be the section generating the $k$th factor of $\mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus r}$. For every $k=1,\ldots,n$ we can, after shrinking $U$ to a small neighborhood of $x$, lift $\psi(e_k)$ to a section $\widetilde{e}_k$ of $\mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus n}$ over $U$. This gives a morphism of sheaves $\alpha: \mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus r} \to \mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus n}$ such that $\varphi\circ\alpha = \psi$. Similarly, after shrinking $U$, we can find a morphism $\beta:\mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus n} \to \mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus r}$ such that $\psi\circ\beta=\varphi$. Then the map $$\mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus m} \oplus \mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus r} \stackrel{}{\to} \mathcal{F}$$ is a surjection on to the kernel of $\psi$.
To prove (2) we may locally choose a surjection $\eta:\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus r}\to\mathcal{G}$. By part (1) we see $\ker(\theta\circ\eta)$ is of finite type. Since $\ker\theta= \eta(\ker(\theta\circ\eta))$ we win.

The proof above appears on math stack program chapter 17 lemma 11.3. I guess this is a easy lemma because the proof is short but I am not sure if I have understood it correctly.

Let $e_k$ be the section generating the $k-$th factor of $\mathscr O_X^{\oplus r}$.

I think that means $e_k$ is generator for some section $\mathscr O_X(U)$ as a $\mathscr O_X(U)$-module. For example we can assume it to be $1$. Is it correct?

Construction of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I think it needs some easy general result for sets. Namely, for any sets $A,B,C$ and surjective maps $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:C\rightarrow B$ we can always construct maps $\alpha: C\rightarrow A$ and $\beta: A\rightarrow C$ such that $f=g\circ \alpha$ and $g=f\circ \beta$.

The map $\mathscr O_U^{\oplus m}\oplus \mathscr O_U^{\oplus r}\rightarrow \mathscr O_U^{\oplus r}$ is surjective onto the kernel.

First it indeed goes to the kernel. In order to check surjectivity we need to check surjectivity on stalks. We know stalks commute with direct sum and then for every $s\in ker\psi_{x}$ we can choose $t\in \mathscr O_{U,x}$ such that $\chi(t)=\alpha(s)$ because $\chi$ is surjective onto the kernel of $\varphi$. Then $(t,s)$ will be mapped to $s$ under the above map.

For $(2)$ we need that composition of surjective stalk maps is surjective hence composition of surjective sheaf maps is surjective.

Did I understand this proof correctly? Sorry I am quite new to this subject and the question might be dumb. Any help is appreciated.

Hi, this is a suboptimal way to cite the Stacks Project. Please cite by tag - numberings may change, but tags are guaranteed to never change. For instance, this result is Stacks 01BP. Next, please do not include screenshots of text - these are neither accessible nor searchable. Instead, best practice is to copy the text in to your question and format the relevant math using MathJax. Finally, the Stacks Project is an excellent reference work, but it is not the most beginner-friendly. I would suggest potentially starting with a different text.

Thanks. For begineer which text will you recommend? I also tried to read the notes written by one professor in my university but it is even more difficult to understand in my opinion. https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~kraemeth/old-stuff/algebraic-geometry-I/Notes.pdf

Is the scheme Noetherian? Is $\mathscr{F}$ QCoh? I imagine this isn't true in total generality, and my internet isn't loading your Stacks link...

Hi, I've added the text to your post for you - please do that in the future, otherwise it may lead to issues like FShrike experienced above. For textbooks, Vakil or Hartshorne are common choices of introductory texts.

Your first point is almost correct: $e_k$ is considered to represent the global section which is $1$ on the $k$-th factor of $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus r}(X)$ (and $0$ alsewhere): then the $\mathcal{O}_X$-module structure ensures that $e_k$ restricts to the section of $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus r}(U)$ which is just $1$ on the $k$-th factor again, for any open $U$.
For the construction of the maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the set property you mention is true, but insufficient in our case. Imagine if $A$, $B$ and $C$ were modules over some ring (or simply abelian groups), and $f$ and $g$ were module morphisms, then you'd want $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to respect the module structure as well ! However, this is not always possible: think for instance about the case $$A = \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z \xrightarrow{\text{id}} \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z \hspace{1cm} C =\Bbb Z \xrightarrow{\text{mod }2} \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$$ these are surjective group homomorphisms, but the only factorization as group homomorphisms $A = \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z \rightarrow C = \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$ is trivial. Although, you could easily find a set-theoretic factorization $A \rightarrow C$, by sending $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{1}$ to $0$ and $1$ respectively.
The real statement you are looking for is an analogue of the following:

Let $R$ be a ring, and $M \xrightarrow{f} N \rightarrow 0$ a surjective morphism of $R$-modules. If $R^I \xrightarrow{g} N$ is a (not necessarily surjective) morphism of $R$-modules from a free $R$-module $R^I$, then there exists a (non-unique) factorization $h:R^I \rightarrow M$ such that $g = f \circ h$.

Graphically, here is what is happening:

This is easily understood: let $(e_i)_I$ be the standard basis of $R^I$, let $h(e_i) \in M$ be any element mapping to $g(e_i)$ via $f$ (which exists, because $f$ is surjective). Because $h$ was specified on a basis, it uniquely extends as an $R$-module map. Notice that because there might be multiple choices for $h(e_i)$, $h$ is not unique. In essence, we have reduced to the case of set-theoretic choice.
If you want some reference, the property above says that $R^I$ (i.e. free $R$-modules) are projective objects in the category of $R$-modules. These are exactly the objects through which epimorphisms ($\approx$ surjections) can be extended.
Here, the proof is using the fact that $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus l}(U)$ are projective modules over $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ because they are free (and then extends to a map of $\mathcal{O}_U$-modules, as maps between free sheaves over $\mathcal{O}_U$ are determined by the map between global sections). But notice that we can only apply this locally (hence the restriction to $U$), because a surjective map of sheaves only implies surjective maps between sections locally. (In particular, this means that although it is tempting to say so, $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus l}$ are not necessarily projective  objects in the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules ; I encourage you to try and work out how it fails)
I hope this answers (most of) your questions !

Thank you for taking your time to give me detailed answer. Let me write a short overview for your answer. For the construction of $\alpha,\beta$, one need freeness or more precisely projectiveness of the module instead of the general set theoretic property. For counterexample one can think $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module, because it is not even torsion free. But as sheaves it is not a projecctive object but locally is so. Why it fails is in my opinion more or less definition.
